# Python properties not returning actual value

Tags: python-3.x

I am learning Python and have created a class for test purpose.

The problem is whenever I call Wallet.Blanc it returns the property and not the float value.

Probably a simple question :)

My code is:

```
class Wallet:

    def __init__(self, starting_amount):
        self.__balance = starting_amount

    @property
    def Balance(self):
        return self.__balance
    
    def Withdraw(self, amount:float):
        if amount <= self.__amount:
            self.__amount -= amount
        else:
            raise Exception("Not enough balance")

    def Deposit(self, amount:float):
        self.__amount += amount
```

And main.py:

```
from wallet import Wallet
wallet = Wallet(10000)        
print("Wallet starting at: " + Wallet.Balance)
```

I get this result:

Wallet starting at: <property object at 0x000001E45B15A6B0>

I would expect:

Wallet starting at: 10000

Comment: Use print("Wallet starting at: " + str(Wallet.Balance))

Comment: You should invoke it from the instance which is `wallet` not from the class (`Wallet` with capital "W"). This is by design, and how properties work in Python.

Comment: Doh! So simpel. Thanks.